# simple javascript if else not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is really weird, this has never happen before. I'm sure the solution is right in front of my eyes...

A simple javascript if else on a string returned from a `$.post`

```
$.post("login.php", {
    user_id : user_id
  }, function(result) {

   alert(result); //result if a returned string from login.php: echo 'pswd';

    if (result == "error") { alert(1);
    } else if (result == "pswd") { alert(2);
    } else { alert(3); }
});
```

**For some reason the if else statement is passing through `result == "pswd"` and executing `alert(3);`
I'm sure I have had similar scenarios working as expected. What am I missing?**

Comment: obviously `result` is not equal to `"error"` or `"pswd"`. Most likely it has an extra space or character that you didn't expect. *Find a dupe!*

Comment: I would suggest using debug tools to set a breakpoint in your browser to verify the value of result.

Comment: Nope, result is definitely "error" or "pswd" (i have double checked for spaces, etc).

Comment: Replace the alert with `alert((typeof result) + ' ' + encodeURIComponent(result))` and show us the result. (you can also use console.log instead of alert if you have access to the console)

Comment: When given the option that either your string is not what you think it is or comparisons are broken in javascript I'll guess the former every time.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like its erroring.  If you take the code below and leave out the var declaration.  The it will give the "start" alert.  But the if's will fail to show an alert.  I think because the var is technically null at that point.

Or you have hidden characters in the returned string.  Might want to check the character lenth of the returned string to see if it is indeed the value you "see".

You may need to declare the var before passing it to the function that your expecting a returning value from.    I'm not big on using ByRef's in javascript.  So I may be wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
    var result = "pswd"

    alert("start");

    if (result == "error") 
    { 
        alert("error");
    } else if (result == "pswd") {
        alert("good"); 
    } else {
        alert("no match"); 
    }

    alert("done");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This really doesn't pertain. He's defining the variable as an argument to the function.

Comment: No. The variable is defined in the function header of the function that is called when the ajax call returns. And no, in your code it is not because the variable is null that you don't get an alert, it is because the variable `result` is unknown. Just look at the error console. And if it was defined but no value was assigned to it (like `var result;`), the value is `undefined`.

Comment: Just wondering about jscript then .... on an undefined variable can you use ==.... vs =     Dont really understand the down votes... because I was just detailing the actual logical explanation of the code he provided....